# Submitting Flash Builder 4.6 Application to Appstore: unsupported architecture(s): arm

Tags: ios, flash, air, adobe, app-store

this is really puzzling me: my flash-builder 4.6 application works fine with the ad-hoc distribution profile. but when i try to submit the .ipa-file via the application-loader, i always get this error:

iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable contains unsupported architecture(s): arm

i also tried to put the armv6/armv7 keys into the infoadditions. nothing seems to help. any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same problem and it turned out to be a problem with the Application Loader and Lion OS.  I was able to upload the same .ipa file that had this error when I used a computer running the OSX 10.6

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://devgirl.org/2011/06/20/flexair-for-ios-development-process-explained/ and here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/418851

It seems that you have to add

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
<string>wifi</string>
<string>armv6</string>
<string>armv7</string>
</array>
```

to your `<infoAdditions>` tag!

Comment: Well i have those keys in my infoadditions. Still get the same error.